# VBA Variable passed into function

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am having difficulty with passing a variable to a function. The variable name I place into the function may vary, therefore I have used another variable "x". 
What am I missing? "myVar" simply will not equal the array name (e.g. arrNames(2) = Nancy) I pass into the function.

```
Public Const intContestants = 7
Public intRandom, myVar, x As Integer

Public Function arrContestants(x As Integer) As String

    ReDim arrNames(0 To intContestants) As Variant

        'set contestant names to assingments in array
        arrNames(0) = "Kathleen "
        arrNames(1) = "Bruce "
        arrNames(2) = "Nancy"
        arrNames(3) = "Katherine"
        arrNames(4) = "Debra"
        arrNames(5) = "Glenn"
        arrNames(6) = "Andrew"
        arrNames(7) = "Willy"

    myVar = arrContestants(x)

End Function


Public Sub Roll()

        intRandom = Int((intContestants - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        myVar = arrContestants(intRandom)
        ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Contestant").OLEFormat.Object.Value = myVar

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that instead of this line:

```
myVar = arrContestants(x)
```

you meant:

```
arrContestants = arrNames(x)
```

Comment: Thank you I knew it had to be something minor.